# Amazon s3 strange error while uploading image. Please suggest

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Using the following code in my Android activity:

```
CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
                getApplicationContext(),    
                "eu-central-1:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",    
                Regions.EU_CENTRAL_1           
        );

        AmazonS3 s3 = new AmazonS3Client(credentialsProvider);
        TransferUtility transferUtility = new TransferUtility(s3, getApplicationContext());

       File file= new File("/storage/extSdCard/Sweee/app/src/main/res/mipmap-xxhdpi/ic_launcher.png");
        TransferObserver observer = transferUtility.upload(
                "aaa.bbb",     
                "test"+file.getName(),    
               file      
        );
```

got the error: Error during upload: 1

> com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: The bucket you are
>   attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint

Comment: Are you sure your bucket was created in the `eu-central-1` region?

Comment: thats why I mentioned the identity id prefix in the code have a look..

Comment: poolid is eu-central-1:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX indicates the region right?

Comment: The `region` in the `CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider` constructor is the region to use when contacting Cognito Identity. Just to make sure `AmazonS3Client` uses the correct region and not the default one, what happens if you try to set it explicitly like this `s3.setEndpoint("s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com");` (before instantiating the `TransferUtility`)?

Comment: @Khalid T thanks that part of code was essential

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this really worked for me Thanks @Khalid for your suggestion it was needed too (this code  made the image url publicly accessible as well):

```
BasicAWSCredentials basicAWSCredentials=new BasicAWSCredentials("XXXXXXXXXXX", "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
            AmazonS3 aS3 = new AmazonS3Client(basicAWSCredentials);
            aS3.setEndpoint("https://s3-eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/");

            File file= new File("/storage/extSdCard/Sweee/app/src/main/res/mipmap-xxhdpi/ic_launcher.png");

            PutObjectRequest putObj=new PutObjectRequest("aaa.bbbb", "test_navin1/"+file.getName(),file);

            //making the object Public
            putObj.setCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead);

            aS3.putObject(putObj);
```